# KIBANA and ELASTICSEARCH config CA

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, alert, elastic-stack

im new on ELK stack,i am lead to Kibana Alert config but i got stuck at Kibana and Elastic search CA step when follow this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/configuring-tls.html#configuring-tls-kib-es

- elasticsearch.yml

```
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: transport_key.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: transport_key.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: http.p12
```

- kibana.yml

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "kibana_password"
kibana.index: ".kibana"
xpack.security.encryptionKey: "32 random letters"
csp.strict: true
xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: "32 random letters"

server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.certificate: "/path/to/kibana-server.crt"
server.ssl.key: "/path/to/kibana-server.key"
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "path/to/config/elasticsearch-ca.pem" ]
```

when i started kibana by./bin/kibana promt show me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeUWK.png)

I run on: ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, and ELL run install dicrectly. Please tell me what i was wrong.

Comment: Are you certain that ES is up?

Comment: Yes, i started ES before Kibana.